# How to understand given sysdate is Date or Timestamp

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a procedure.It takes date parameter with type Date.What i want to know is the other users send sysdate to my procedure.Which format they send sysdate to my procedure?

For example:
01/02/2021 or 01/02/2020 00:00:00(timestamp)

Does my procedure accepts all sending formats?Maybe Date type converts sending formats this style 01/02/2020.I am not sure.

I mean that does my Date parameter accepts all date formats because I want to use date in my procedure without seconds or minutes.

My procedure is

```
DECLARE
var_P_DATE                DATE;    (for example : 01/01/2021)
BEGIN
 SELECT last_day(var_P_DATE) INTO v_last_day FROM DUAL; (31/01/2021)
 if v_last_day = var_P_DATE (it returns false because no second or minutes)
  .....
END;
```

I used DBMS.OUTPUT. I think Date type converts just like this 01/02/2021 and i do not get any error but i am not sure.

Comment: Your initial mistake is that you incorrectly assume that Oracle's [DATE data type](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-5405B652-C30E-4F4F-9D33-9A4CB2110F1B) has a format. It doesn't. And if you are referring to Oracle's built-in [SYSDATE function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SYSDATE.html#GUID-807F8FC5-D72D-4F4D-B66D-B0FE1A8FA7D2) then it returns a DATE value. Hence no need to consider format at all.

Comment: In addition to what has been said, but you may already know that: Oracle doesn't have a real date type. They do have a datetime type they call `DATE` unfortunately. So whenever you want to deal with dates only, you must be aware that you may need to remove the time part. In tables you will either prevent datetimes with a time part to get inserted via a check constraint or by removing the time part in a trigger. For function parameters you will do the same: either return an error when the datetime constains a time part or remove the time part silently.

Comment: if you want to see roughly what it looks like run the following: select dump(sysdate) from dual; That is as close as you will get the seeing the internal structure of a date. But be careful what you get will not be what you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your procedure will only ever receive a `date`, because that is the data type of the formal parameter. When the procedure is called the caller can supply a `date`, or something that can be implicitly converted to a `date` (though they shouldn't; implicit conversions are generally a bad thing, particularly from strings).

The `date` data type includes time components. If you are being passed a date with a non-midnight time that you want to ignore, such as `sysdate`, you can use [the `trunc()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TRUNC-date.html#GUID-BC82227A-2698-4EC8-8C1A-ABECC64B0E79), with it's default `'DD'` format; and you don't need to `select from dual`:

```
v_last_day := last_day(trunc(var_P_DATE));
```

If the caller passes in `systimestamp` then that will still be implcitly converted to a `date` by the time you see it - which means it loses any fractional seconds and time zone information, but retains hours, minutes and seconds.

Dates and timestamps do not have have any inherent human-readable format. A date can be displayed using various formats - [see the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-49B32A81-0904-433E-B7FE-51606672183A) - either explicitly with `to_char()` and a format model, or implicitly using your session settings.

When you do

```
dbms_output.put_line(var_P_DATE);
```

you are doing an implicit conversion of the `date` value to a string, using the session's `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` setting. So, different users might see that in different formats. You have no control over that. If you want to see a specific format then specify that, e.g.:

```
dbms_output.put_line(to_char(var_P_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

You also have no control over whether the caller sees that output - it's down to the application/client and its settings. It looks like you are probably only using it for debugging the comparison issue though, so that probably doesn't matter here.

So as a demonstration:

```
declare
  var_P_DATE date := sysdate;
  v_last_day date;
begin
  v_last_day := last_day(var_P_DATE);
  dbms_output.put_line(to_char(v_last_day, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
  v_last_day := last_day(trunc(var_P_DATE));
  dbms_output.put_line(to_char(v_last_day, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
end;
/

2021-02-28 09:59:02
2021-02-28 00:00:00
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=827814ded7bff26e3321e997b9198cf7)

Answer (score 1):

Just apply `TRUNC()` function and use that variable of type `DATE` within the procedure after defining the data type of `var_P_DATE` as `TIMESTAMP`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE myproc( var_P_DATE TIMESTAMP) AS
 dt DATE := TRUNC(var_P_DATE) ;
BEGIN
   ...
   ...
END;
/
```

If you mean `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` by `DBMS.OUTPUT`, then that's completely irrelevant with your current conversion, that's just used to display result to the console as a string.

Answer (score 1):

Date type in Oracle has hours, minutes and seconds, timestamp has fractions:

```
SQL> declare
  2     vDate date := sysdate;
  3     vTimeStamp timestamp := systimestamp;
  4  begin
  5     dbms_output.put_line('Date: ' || vDate);
  6     dbms_output.put_line('Timestamp: ' || vTimestamp);
  7  end;
  8  /
Date: 2021-02-18 09:49:32
Timestamp: 18-FEB-21 09.49.32.015953 AM
```

If you want to use just the date part, with no time, of a `date` variable, use something like  `trunc(vDate)`:

```
SQL> declare
  2     vDate date := sysdate;
  3     vTimeStamp timestamp := systimestamp;
  4  begin
  5     dbms_output.put_line('Date: ' || vDate);
  6     dbms_output.put_line('Date truncated: ' || trunc(vDate));
  7     dbms_output.put_line('Timestamp: ' || vTimestamp);
  8  end;
  9  /
Date: 2021-02-18 09:51:51
Date truncated: 2021-02-18 00:00:00
Timestamp: 18-FEB-21 09.51.51.024384 AM
```

An example of how comparison works on `date` variables:

```
SQL> declare
  2      vDate1  date;
  3      vDate2  date;
  4  begin
  5      vDate1 := sysdate;
  6      dbms_lock.sleep(5); /* wait 5 seconds */
  7      vDate2 := sysdate;
  8      --
  9      if vDate1 = vDate2 then
 10          dbms_output.put_line('Equal');
 11      else
 12          dbms_output.put_line('NOT equal');
 13      end if;
 14      --
 15      if trunc(vDate1) = trunc(vDate2) then
 16          dbms_output.put_line('Equal, truncated');
 17      else
 18          dbms_output.put_line('NOT equal, truncated');
 19      end if;
 20  end;
 21  /
NOT equal
Equal, truncated
```

Comment: In my if blog , I want to compare dates(given and last day of current moth)  so I do not need any trunc func etc..Am i right?

Comment: If you have `date` variables and you only want to compare the date part, and not the time, you need to `trunc`

Comment: Thank you very much.I will use trunc before comparision.